# add_recation is Yellow Highlighted

Tags: python, discord.py

Does anyone know, why this code isn´t working? In pycharm add_reaction is yellow Highlighted and shows me: **Unresolved attribute reference 'add_reaction' for class 'Bot'**

````
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == "951577233007448074":
        await bot.add_reaction(message, "951904925472919614")```
````

Comment: I guess a typo here. It should be `Bot.add_reaction(message, "951904925472919614")`.

Comment: Should it be `add_reaction` not `add_rection`?

Comment: The error does not match the code.  Error message has `add_reaction`, but code has `add_rection`.  Note the spelling difference.

Comment: In the code it was written correctly, I only made a mistake here. Anyway, it still does not work.

Comment: What do you want to do? Add a reaction to a specific message or a reaction to every message in the channel?

Answer (score 1):

Your code will never work in that way. It looks like you want to add a specific reaction to every message in the channel.

**First thing I noticed:** You do not put ID's into quotation marks. Simply remove `""` when you want to compare/use an ID.

**Secondly:** You normally do not use `bot.add_reaction` if you did not define where you want to add the reaction to.

**Thirdly:** The `on_message` event normally just takes `message` and not `message, bot` as an argument.

If you want to add a specific reaction to **every** message in the channel you can **simply use:**

```py
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == 951577233007448074:
        await message.add_reaction("YourReactionHere")
```